# adding onClickListener from separate class to xml layout

Tags: android, class, events, onclick, external

I have separate file with listener.
I want to attach that listener to button, using xml Android:onClick, but after compilling i get error

```
01-11 14:35:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(4682): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Btnlistener(View) in the activity class com.android.app.Activity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn1'
```

Is there any fancy way to import my listener class, in such way that i could use Android:onClick in xml.

Comment: there is not. if your callback is a listener, you need to add it in java. in xml you can only add a callbakc that is a function in your activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I suggest:

Have a `BaseActivity` with the code for your listener, in a normal method

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
   // put here what your listener did
}
```

And make all your activities that need this listener `extends BaseActivity`. You can define in your layouts the following xml element for buttons:

```
android:onClick="buttonClicked"
```

Comment: Hmm, seems it's better than mine solution, I probably implement this.

Answer (score 0):

when you set onClick in xml then the activity class which inflate the xml must declare onClick event as a method, for example:

in XML:

```
onClick="btnAdd"
```

and in your activity:

```
public void btnAdd(View v){
//your code when the button click event is captured
}
```

Comment: Ok, i dealt with it in other way... 
I added handle in activity that sets onClickListener to clicked button, and performs a click, so code will be a bit nicer:)

Comment: well, as i have multiple activities i wanted to make external listener class, to avoid making separated class in any activity.
But anyway thx for help.